# time.strftime() not updaing

Tags: python, time, module

I am trying to get the time when a button is pushed, but I am going to have a few pushes without starting and calling the time module. In Ipython, I tested out some code, and the time is not updating

```
import time
t = time.strftime("%b-%d-%y at %I:%m%p")
print(t)
#do something else for a little
t = time.strftime("%b-%d-%y at %I:%m%p")
print(t)
```

It gives me the same time

even if I put in a time tuple such as:

```
lt = time.localtime(time.time())
t = time.strftime("%b-%d-%y at %I:%m%p", lt)
print(t)
```

I get the same time

Even if I wait, and execute the code again (in Ipython), it gives me the same time.

time.time() will give me a new time every time though

I don't know if doing it in Ipython (I'm just testing code before I put it in my python file) matters

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `%m` at `%I:%m%p` to format your "minutes", which actually means a **month** in decimals. Try capital `%M`instead to get the minutes.

So,

```
time.strftime("%b-%d-%y at %I:%M%p")
```

See [strftime documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) for the format directives.

Comment: *facepalm* holy crap how did I not see that. Thank you so much, I thought I was going crazy!

Comment: I was very very confused for a moment too, since I by incident started testing it at exactly 6:09PM.